# How to approach Android tabs and subtabs

Tags: android, tabs

I am looking to create an Android application that uses Tabs.

### Requirements

> When a user selects a tab and gets back to the same tab, there shouldn't be a loading period (preferably).
>
> Each tab will contain a listview.
>
> In one of the tabs, I will have to use subtabs.

And that's it.

One great example I really liked (although I didn't try the app) is http://www.usatoday.com/android/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just developed a tabbed application and I used the following function to create tabs in code. The function uses intents which mean when ever a tab is selected an Activity is loaded in the tab body using intent. This function is called in main activity.

```
private void SetupTabs()
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  
        Intent intent;  

        //*****************************
        intent = new Intent().setClass(MPaper.this, NewsList.class);        
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(NewsTag).setIndicator("News")
                      .setContent(intent);        
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        //*****************************
        intent = new Intent().setClass(MPaper.this, Search.class);        
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(SearchTag).setIndicator("Search")
                      .setContent(intent);        
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        //****************************
        intent = new Intent().setClass(MPaper.this, MyNewsList.class);        
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(MyNewsTag).setIndicator("My News")
                      .setContent(intent);        
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        //*****************************
        intent = new Intent().setClass(MPaper.this, Extras.class);        
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(ExtrasTag).setIndicator("Extras")
                      .setContent(intent);        
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        //*****************************


        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(NewsTag);
    }
```

The list view in NewsList Activity is made by XML as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/NewsList" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In Response to Fabios' comment below:
Yes wither use visibility property or try implementing tabs using the way mentioned below:

```
private void TabSetup()
    {
        tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);        
        tabs.setup(); 
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("MainNewsTag");
        spec.setContent(R.id.MainNews);
        spec.setIndicator("Home");
        tabs.addTab(spec);




        spec = tabs.newTabSpec("SearchTag");
        spec.setContent(R.id.Search);
        spec.setIndicator("Search");
        tabs.addTab(spec);


        spec = tabs.newTabSpec("MyNewsTag");
        spec.setContent(R.id.MyNews);
        spec.setIndicator("My News");
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        spec = tabs.newTabSpec("ExtrasTag");
        spec.setContent(R.id.MyNews);
        spec.setIndicator("Extras");
        tabs.addTab(spec);
}
```

Where as Layout file is as below:

```
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TableLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent">
               <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
               <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent" >  
                   <ListView android:id="@+id/MainNews" 
                             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                   </ListView>
.... and so on
```

Comment: Mmm... That sounds good. Have you thought of a way to support subtabs like in the USA today example I mentioned in the question? For the subtabs I also could simply play with the visibility of the properties. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Just a few more questions UmairP: 1) The code you displayed in your first and second interventions are different solutions, right? 2) In the second case, I noticed you use a FrameLayout. Are you able to click on a list item and go to a different activity with a different view and the tabs will go away? The same in the first case?

Comment: 1) Yes the two are two solutions for same problem. I am suggesting that you use 1st solution for main tabs and try if the 2nd solution works for sub tabs (I am not sure though). 2) Yes, once you click a listitem and if you have implemented intents then the tabs will go away and new activity will be displayed.

Comment: Then Thanks because that's exactly the answer I was hoping to get!

Answer (score 2):

Two thinks you need to consider:

1.) Subtabs cannot be implemented using Activities, since an `ActivityGroup` cannot wrap another `ActivityGroup`

2.) Tabs in Tabs blow up Layout complexity quite a bit. Especially on < 2.0 devices you'll easily run into `StackOverflowExceptions`. There was also a blog post about it on the official android blog, I'll update the answer when I find it.

[EDIT]
There we go: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/future-proofing-your-apps.html

The relevant part is:

> Due to changes in the View rendering infrastructure, unreasonably deep (more than 10 or so) or broad (more than 30 total) View hierarchies in layouts are now likely to cause crashes. This was always a risk for excessively complex layouts, but you can think of Android 1.5 as being better than 1.1 at exposing this problem.

Considering that every tabhost adds about 4 layers of depth, you'll reach a depth of 10 with double tabs pretty soon.

Keep in mind that "using activities" as tabs is just a sham, they are just additional views within your hierarchy.

Comment: That sounds not very promising considering that I need to have the application ready and working on an Android in November 30th. I'll try to find that blog post too and check for your answer to see it here if you find it first. Thanks Timo!

Comment: Yes, thanks for this important insights. Although I selected the other answer as the correct answer, I also appreciated your efforts and will keep them in mind. Judging by the short time you've been here, you'll earn great reputation in stackoverflow. Thanks!